# Trying to SaveAs excel workbook using VBA and specific network path

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016, save-as

I'm trying to use VBA code to save an excel workbook with a specific file name based on cell data and in a specific network folder. Here's the code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Path As String
Dim FileName1 As String
Dim FileName2 As String
Path = "H:\testing folder\"
FileName1 = Range("A8")
FileName2 = Range("A11")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FileName1 & "_" & FileName2 & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
End Sub
```

the file is just being saved in the H drive and not the testing folder in the H drive. Also, the activeworkbook line did have Filename:=Path & FileName1 etc. but it was saving in the same place with the name of the path end folder in front of "FileName1".

Comment: What's in Cells A8 and A11

Comment: Just some part numbers and such. Nothing that would be an invalid file character. The issue is its not saving where I want it to. Maybe the syntax is filepath, not path?

Comment: So when you debug, what is the value of FileName1 & FileName2?

Comment: Ah I see, the first problem, number 1, is you need to use the whole file path in your `...Workbook.SaveAs`. See below answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim Path As String
Dim FileName1 As String
Dim FileName2 As String
Path = "H:\testing folder\"
FileName1 = Range("A8")
FileName2 = Range("A11")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & FileName1 & "_" & FileName2 & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, and Aldert, the value is what is in the cell, in this case for testing purposes, those values were "testing" and "TESTING".

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest some tips when working with paths:

> 1. Create your folder before using it
> 2. Check that Range is filled with some text (specially with ranges)
> 3. Create the FileName argument in a separate string instead of inside the function (so it can be inspected before hand)

Here is an example of how you try this explained tips and for further projects!
Good luck mate!

**> Your code**

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

  Dim strPath As String
  Dim strFileName_ As String

    '(1. Create your folder before using it)
    'Create folders if necessary (Return path as String)
    strPath = Create_Path("H:\testing folder\")

    
    'Get range with File.Name
    Set Rng_ = Union(Range("A8"), Range("A11"))     'Each range should be filled only with names (without extension nor Path)
    Rng_.Select
    
    'Get FileName for each Range
    For Each text_ In Rng_
        '(2. Check that Range is filled with some text (specially with ranges))
        If Len(text_) = 0 Then Err.Raise 100, , "There is no text in range"

         '(3. Create the FileName argument in a separate string instead of inside the function (so it can be inspected before hand))
        strFileName_ = strPath & text_
        
        'Save as xlOpenXMLWorkbook = 51
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=strFileName_, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
        'Check other FileFormat Constants at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat
    Next

End Sub
```

**Auxiliar function to Create a folder path**

```
Function Create_Path(ByVal strPath As Variant) As String
     
    strDriver = Split(strPath, ":")(0) & ":"    'If the drive is not specified, the new directory or folder is created on the current drive.
    If Dir(strPath, vbDirectory) = "" Then      'Tests if strPath is already created
            MkDir strPath                       'Create a directory or folder
    End If

    'Fill function variable
    Create_Path = strPath

End Function
```